# React not taking local images

Tags: reactjs, masonry

So I use masonry to create a image gallery.
The structure is like this

```
const images = [
        "https://res.cloudinary.com/dbmsicu5t/image/upload/v1660382881/1_svyvcu.png",
        "https://res.cloudinary.com/dbmsicu5t/image/upload/v1660382882/2_cferbi.png",
]

<Masonry columnsCount={3} gutter="20px">
                        { images.map((image, i) => (
                            <a data-fancybox="gallery" href={image}>
                                <img
                                    key={i}
                                    src={image}
                                    style={{width: "100%", display: "block", cursor: "pointer"}}
                                    alt={''}/>
                            </a>
                        ))}
</Masonry>
```

My Folder structure is like this

```
src
----assets
----------1.PNG
----components
--------------Header
--------------------Header.jsx
--------------Footer
```

When I try to use a file path like src/assets/1.PNG instead of the url, I get no image.

Comment: try importing the image like `import Image from "../relative/path/to/img_file.png"` and try using it as `src={Image}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using require method...

```
    const images = [
    {
      img:require("./assets/img1.png")
    },
    {
      img:require("./assets/img2.png")
    }
]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { images.map((image, i) => (
                            <a key={i} data-fancybox="gallery" href={image}>
                                <img
                                    src={image.img}
                                    style={{width: "100%", display: "block", cursor: "pointer"}}
                                    alt={''}/>
                            </a>
                        ))}
    </div>
  );
```

also, always give the `key` attribute to the most outer element inside the `map` method. Here, you were giving it to `img` element which is inside the `anchor` element. It should be given to `anchor` element instead, as it is the most outer element inside the `map` method.